# GridLayout inicar con campos ya seleccionados

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayaout

Tengo un `GridLayout` en el cual, cuando se pulsa sobre uno de sus items se cambia el **color de fondo** y el **color de letra** y además **se asigna "1" en un elemento del objeto mp y en la variable "pulsado"** para saber que está seleccionado.

Estoy implementando el *"modificar"* y necesito que cuando se incie el *GridLayout*, los item que en el objeto mP tienen asignado 1 aparezca ya con el fondo de color y la letra blanca y la variable pulsado a "1", y los que tengan el valor "0" se inicien con el fondo blanco, al letra de color y pulsado a "0".

Para ello he puesto un witch con if en el método `onBindViewHolder`donde cambio el fondo y el color (que lo ahce bien) y cambio el valor de **"puslsado"** que no lo ahce bien, y por tanto en el metodo `onClcik` las cosas no funcionan bien porque **pulsado no es correcto**.

```
public class ModificarBasico extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

   
    private P mP;

    private int pulsado = 0;

    private GridLayoutManager lLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modificar_basico);
       
        this.layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyGiftList2);

        mP = new P();
        mP = (P)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mP");


        List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(ModificarBasico.this, 3);

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_basico);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewAdapter(ModificarBasico.this, rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);


    }


    private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList() {

        List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Hidratación", R.drawable.hidracicli));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Comida", R.drawable.comida));
        allItems.add(new ItemObject("Teléfono Móvil", R.drawable.movil));

        return allItems;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewHolders> {
        private List<ItemObject> itemList;
        private Context context;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
            ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
            return rcv;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ModificarBasico.RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
            holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
            holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());

    switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    miPlan.setHodratacion(1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    miPlan.setComida(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    miPlan.setMovil(1);
                    break;
        
       }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return this.itemList.size();
        }

    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        public TextView countryName;
        public ImageView countryPhoto;
        public RelativeLayout fondo;

        public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
            fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.i("onClick", "pulsado" +pulsado+"position: "+getAdapterPosition());
            if (pulsado == 0) {
                pulsado = 1;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
                countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        mP.setHodratacion(1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mP.setComida(1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mP.setMovil(1);
                        break;
                 
                }
          

            } else {
                pulsado = 0;
                fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));

                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        mP.setHodratacion(0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mP.setComida(0);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mP.setMovil(0);
                        break;
                    
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

El problema esta que al método **`onBind`** se le llama siempre que se actualiza el `girldLayout`, por tanto para cambiar el color y la variable pulsado de los elementos del `girdLayour` que tengan valor 1 en mi objeto Mp, tengo que hacerlo fuera del onBind, pero no sé donde.